# Error in accessing sitecore in browser via SIM

Tags: sitecore-client, sim

I was trying to access sitecore website instance which I just installed via SIM (Sitecore instance Manager). It seems some settings must have gone wrong while installing sitecore instance. PFA the screenshot from chrome browser below:

[image: Error screenshot of Sitecore website instance accessing in Google Chrome]

Let me also provide the screenshot of SIM paths configured below:
[image]

And I edited the host file at path: "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc" and added the following line: "127.0.0.1      local.tac.ssd" as can be seen in the screenshot attached.
[image]

Comment: Looking at the "Config error" on your screenshot, it looks like this may be the issue you have https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794985/config-error-this-configuration-section-cannot-be-used-at-this-path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please check all options checked in Windows Program and features

[image]

if not checked then please checked all options and then try.

Comment: Yes it worked , Thanks Rishi 